# removing html tag in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an html text as

```
 <span>
    <span class="embed_photo_div" dir="ltr">
        <span class="embed_photo">
            <img src="image.jpg">
        </span>
    </span>
  </span>
```

I am needing the final output as  `<span> </span>` ie the span tag with class embed_photo_div should get removed.

What is the best approach to remove certain sections of htmltext in as3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will can use RegEx match and replace, your pattern:

```
 /<[^<]?span.*class="embed_photo".*>[\w<\s=\".>\r\n\s\t]*</\s?span\s?>/g
```

Link for online example:
http://regexr.com?33tnl

Edited: don't forget escaping characters "/". Added example

```
var x:XML =
    <span>
       <span class="embed_photo_div" dir="ltr">
           <span class="embed_photo">
               <img src="image.jpg"/>
           </span>
       </span>
     </span>;

var str:String = x.toXMLString();

var pattern :RegExp = new RegExp( /<span class="embed_photo"[\r\n\t\s\w=".<>]*[\/>]*[\r\n\t\s]*<\/span>/g );

var output:String = str.replace(pattern, "<span> </span>");

trace(output);
```

Comment: Hi thanks this pattern matches when i use the string.match('/<[^<]?span.*class="embed_photo".*>[\w<\s=\".>\r\n\s\t]*</\s?span\s?>/g') but this is not working with string.replace('/<[^<]?span.*class="embed_photo".*>[\w<\s=\".>\r\n\s\t]*</\s?span\s?>/g', '<span> </span'). if i try to use a regex variable it is giving some  syntactical error on initialization. i have not used regex hence i am not sure if i am missing something. please guide. thanks

Comment: If you would like pattern as string, don't forget escaping characters "/"

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is treat it as xml (after all html is xml) and parse it that way to get at what I want.

Comment: It's the reverse, "all XML are HTML", as you can have a valid HTML file as `<b><i>text</b></i>`, which is not a correct XML. But this approach might work.

Comment: @Vesper Well, HTML won't pass most tiers of validation if you order your nodes incorrectly.

Comment: @MartyWallace the point is true in my case. many of the html tags have not been closed properly. hence i am unable to use this approach.

Comment: @sharmacal If possible by any means, you should try and correct that further upstream (i.e. the HTML itself).

Comment: @MartyWallace that is fetched from backend by calling a url, and i cant change it :)